# What is the difference between a Saved Object and a Snapshot in Kibana

Tags: kibana

You can share links to pages in Kibana using Share|Permalink|Snapshot or Saved Object.   What's the difference between a Snapshot and a Saved Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Snapshot** URL **encodes the current state of your dashboard in the URL**. So, further edits to this saved dashboard won't be visible through this link. We can say that a Snapshot is the one status of the dashboard we want to share, **no matter it is saved or not**.

A **Saved Object** loads the **last saved status** of the dashboard.